# How I change my codename device on Android Device

Tags: android, build, codenameone

I have a question. Some device has codename.

For example:

- Redmi K20Pro has codename "raphael"
- Samsung A02S has codename "A02q"
- Bluestack 5 (my device need change android codename) has codename: "taimen"
- ...

So how I can change this codename through adb shell with root access, or terminal on mobile device, or something like this?
Cause I want to make my virtual device as real as possible. Some applications can only use login on previously logged in devices, but cannot log in on the second device except with the intervention of IT support. So I want to create a perfect 2nd instance to sign in on that device, making that device a perfect version of the first device.

```
 private void writeSessionOS(String str) throws Exception {
    final boolean isRooted = CommonUtils.isRooted(this.crashlyticsCore.getContext());
    writeSessionPartFile(str, SESSION_OS_TAG, new CodedOutputStreamWriteAction() { // from class: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.21
        @Override // com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.CodedOutputStreamWriteAction
        public void writeTo(CodedOutputStream codedOutputStream) throws Exception {
            SessionProtobufHelper.writeSessionOS(codedOutputStream, Build.VERSION.RELEASE, Build.VERSION.CODENAME, isRooted);
        }
    });
    writeFile(str, "SessionOS.json", new FileOutputStreamWriteAction() { // from class: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.22
        @Override // com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.FileOutputStreamWriteAction
        public void writeTo(FileOutputStream fileOutputStream) throws Exception {
            fileOutputStream.write(new JSONObject(new HashMap<String, Object>() { // from class: com.crashlytics.android.core.CrashlyticsController.22.1
                {
                    put("version", Build.VERSION.RELEASE);
                    put("build_version", Build.VERSION.CODENAME);
                    put("is_rooted", Boolean.valueOf(isRooted));
                }
            }).toString().getBytes());
        }
    });
}
```

Any idea about this?

Comment: That is a waste of time. Bluestacks is x86 nor ARM based as it just virtualizes your CPU. As physical devices with x86 CPUs have died out it is not difficult to identify Bluestacks or other emulators by the CPU.

Comment: We have an application can make a fake copy of CPU with ARM based. But I can't change the codename of this device.

Comment: This doesn't seem to be related to `codenameone`